# Electron loadFile is not a function

Tags: electron, knex.js

I'm developing an app using Electron. Using `win.loadFile('index.html')` used to work, but from yesterday it throws an error saying: `win.loadFile is not a function`.

Could it be "Knex.js" which caused this error? Because I installed it recently and the problems began to appear after that. Also, I noticed that Electron icon changed from transparent to a light blue (green) circle.

In addition, Using `loadURL` works but it renders the html file incompletely.

This is my main.js (I removed knex.js code from main.js but didn't help):

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  // and load the index.html of the app.
   win.loadFile('index.html');
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your Electron version. The version of Electron you want to run, install it globally. Here's the issue on GitHub:
[BrowserWindow .loadFile is not a function](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/13984)